# System.Collections.Generic.List<T>.Add(T)' has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, generics

EDIT:

```
List<Organization> orgs = helperDb.QueryAllOnTable("Organization");
```

Model:

```
 public class Organization
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; } 
    }
```

I'm working on generic class that query any table just by passing the modal name table name but I'm stuck here...any help?

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(T)' has some invalid arguments

```
 public List<T> QueryAllOnTable<T>(string table)
        {
            try
            {
                this.OpenConn();

                List<T> lstSelect = new List<T>();
                string SQL = "SELECT * FROM " + table + ";";

                NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(SQL, conn);
                NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        lstSelect.Add(dr[i]); //<<< throwing ERROR
                    } 
                } 
                this.CloseConn();
                return lstSelect;
            }
            catch (Exception ne)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("error on query table connecting to server, Error details {0}", ne.ToString());
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: what was `T` passed as? where are you creating your instance of `T`?

Comment: Why not just cast `dr[i]` to `T`? `lstSelect.Add((T)dr[i]);`

Comment: `dr[i]` is not of type `T`.

Comment: really? what is there to downvote? without any explanation??????

Comment: @AbuHamzah The downvotes are because the answer is so obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dr[i]` is an `object`, you need to explicitly cast it to `T`:

```
lstSelect.Add((T)dr[i])
```

Of course, if the value in the specific data cell is *not* of type T, you'll get a runtime exception.

Comment: how would you deal with the runtime exception? I'm getting runtime error `Message = "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'Models.Organization'."` I have changed my Model from string Id  to Int64 but still the same.

Comment: @AbuHamzah your logic is wrong. You assume every column in your row is of the same type. Rethink about it.